# Jquery animate function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following javascript to animate a div, but the div isn't animating... does anyone know what can be?

JavaScript:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#LayoutDiv1').animate({top: "500px"}, 1500); }); 
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LRuZp/3/

The position property should be specified, when defining top, left, bottom and right properties.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your `div` position to `relative`

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

    position: relative

}
```